# OpenLDAP + Moodle, member of groups

Tags: openldap, moodle

the teachers in my OpenLDAP are in cn=teachers,ou=groups,dc=school,dc=de

the course creator context in my Moodle installation should then be the same if I am not mistaken. If I query ldap

```
BINDUSER="my-bind-user"
LDAPDN="dc=school,dc=de"
BINDPASSWORD="somegreatpassword"
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -H ldaps://school.de:10636 -D "cn=$BINDUSER,ou=ldap,$LDAPDN" -w $BINDPASSWORD -b "cn=teachers,ou=groups,$LDAPDN"
```

the query yields my teachers as expected. But my moodle installation seems to ignore this setting. Did I make some obvious mistake?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i copied a wrong configuration for moodle. the member id is "member" not "memberuid".

this can be closed. sorry.